# glfwJoystickIsGampad returns false for Controller

Tags: c++, glfw

I am working on a game engine in c++ and im using glfw 3.3.5 on Windows. Im currently working on the Input System but when i connect a switch pro controller glfwJoystickIsPresent returns true however glfwJoystickIsGampad returns false.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

GLFW up until 3.3.8 (the most recent version I have tested myself) does not go well with Nintendo's Pro Controller.
See e.g. this issue: https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/1627